# Sometimes textureview getbitmap returns "black" bitmap

Tags: android, bitmap

Sometimes textureView getBitmap() returns ugly bitmap, it looks full black(I tried save to gallery, I tried set to imageview ), but if I check pixels of bitmap, pixels is colored normally. What is it?

Comment: Hi did you figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

Very probably the dimension of Bitmap is too large, causing Android refuse to render it.

You can use Bitmap.Options in decoding the dimension first.

Set inJustDecodeBounds=true in Options object.

Decode Bitmap with that Options object

The dimension of the Bitmap is inside Options.outWidth and Options.outHeight

If the image is too large, try to instantiate another Options object

and then set inSampleSize=2 or 4 or 8 to make the resultant image smaller

Then it should be able to show

Comment: No, textureView.getBitmap() gives me bitmap with normal size, as usual.

Comment: Is it a problem of a specific image file (control experiment on 2 different Bitmap)? or is it a problem of the TextureView (control experiment on ImageView vs TextureView)?

Comment: It is problem with TextureView.